# Jquery change logo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make the logo white when the pic has a dark contrast and the opposite with it's on white mode . I have tried adding class with jquery but it doesn't work. even with css i think that i have problem at "if($(".carousel-item").hasClass("black-logo")){....."
Any help is appreciated!

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($(".carousel-item").hasClass("black-logo")){
        $("img.logo2").addClass("hide-logo");
        $("img.logo1").removeClass("hide-logo");
    }


});
```

```css
body{
    
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.top{
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
       transition: 1s ease;
}
a:hover {
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slider{
    height: 100vh;
}
.row.logo-section {
    position: absolute;
   top: 8%;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.row.top {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
}
.hide-logo{
    display: none;
}
.row.slider .col-md-12{
padding: 0;
}
.carousel-item {
    transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>web site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="assets/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row top">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: right;">
        <div>
            <a href="#"> Photography by ©Mohamed Amine Charbti</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row logo-section">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left;">
        <div>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/logojin.png" class="img-fluid logo1 hide-logo"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/logojin2.png" class="img-fluid logo2"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row slider">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="assets/images/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item black-logo">
              <img src="assets/images/16.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/6.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/7.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/8.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/9.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/10.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <img src="assets/images/11.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/12.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/13.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/14.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/15.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/16.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/17.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/18.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/19.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/20.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </div> 
</div>   




    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did my solution helped you ? If it did - Please do not forget to upvote and accept as "the" answer

Answer (score 0):

in case you can use plain js, you can use `toggle` in this way:

```js
// Here you will get a node list of items, is better use an id to get the item
// const carouselItem = document.getElementByClassName("carousel-item")

const carouselElement = document.getElementById("carourel-element");
const hasBlackLogoClass = carouselElement.classList.contains("black-logo");
const firstLogo = document.querySelectorAll("img.logo1");
const secondLogo = document.querySelectorAll("img.logo2");

firstLogo.classList.toggle("hide-logo", hasBlackLogoClass);
secondLogo.classList.toggle("hide-logo", !hasBlackLogoClass);
```

Comment: Have you tested your solution and answer at all ? In the question there is no ID as `carourel-element` its a class only. Your code will not work as it will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

Comment: It will work with a little modfiication, for this reason I add the comment "Here you will get a node list of items, is better use an id to get the item"

Comment: You can try to see with `className` as well. Its not working as required by OP.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is that you are NOT checking all the `carousel-item` classes.

You need to use `$.each` to loop through all the item and then `removeClass` hide-logo from your logo.

Read more about $.each [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Run Snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Item
  var carouselItem = $('.carousel-item')

  //Loop through each .carousel-item
  $.each(carouselItem, function(i, key) {
    if ($(key).hasClass('black-logo')) {
      $(".logo2").addClass("hide-logo");
      $(".logo1").removeClass("hide-logo");
      console.log('black-logo class found in divs = '+i)
      console.log('hide-logo Class removed from logo1')
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>web site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="assets/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row top">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: right;">
        <div>
          <a href="#"> Photography by ©Mohamed Amine Charbti</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row logo-section">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left;">
        <div>
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/logojin.png" class="img-fluid logo1 hide-logo"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/logojin2.png" class="img-fluid logo2"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row slider">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="assets/images/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item black-logo">
              <img src="assets/images/16.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item black-logo">
              <img src="assets/images/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="assets/images/4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```